# In need of driver for C-Media CMI8788

Tags: drivers

I have a HT Omega eClaro in a system that I use for ripping vinyl. Will I ever be able to use this machine it with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the Oxygen HD chipset works with 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10, it's pretty clear that the Oxygen HD drivers are mature and work.
However, as I waded through the morass of opinion and less than useful "solutions", I uncovered a BUG REPORT that indicates someone in the land of the devs Dropped The Ball with 12.04 and also 12.10 Oxygen HD support:
[[AV200 - Oxygen HD Audio - Asus Xonar D1] analog output device is not listed in audio settings](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/936539)

Answer (score 0):

I have this card as well, and it does work in ubuntu 12.04, but not out of the box, and I'm still trying to get everything to work with it.

I followed this guide here to rip out PulseAudio and ALSA and replace them with OSS4, and once I did that I was able to get basic sound output, at least.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound