# HT Omega eClaro sound card (C-Media CMI8788) won't load in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, alsa, soundcard

*Disclaimer: I also posted this question [at LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/ht-omega-eclaro-alsa-oxygen-hd-wont-load-under-mint-14-a-4175443344/). I have Mint 14 (based on Ubuntu 12.10) installed right now, but this problem exists with stock Ubuntu 12.10 as well.  If you insist, I can install straight Ubuntu 12.10 for the purposes of troubleshooting.*

I have an  [HT Omega eClaro sound card](http://www.htomega.com/eclaro.html) based on the C-Media CMI8788 which is supported under ALSA with the [snd-oxygen module](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-oxygen). The card is not loaded by ALSA as a sound device either at boot time or by modprobing.

Relevant output of `lspci`

```
04:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
```

Output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                     HDA NVidia at 0xf6080000 irq 17
1 [Q9000          ]: USB-Audio - QuickCam Pro 9000
                     Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Pro 9000 at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3.1, high speed
```

The snd-oxygen module is not loaded at boot (not listed under `lsmod`).  After I run `sudo modprobe snd-oxygen` the module loads but the device is still not accessible to `alsamixer`.

```
snd_oxygen             20948  0 
snd_oxygen_lib         41273  1 snd_oxygen
snd_mpu401_uart        14169  1 snd_oxygen_lib
```

Some possibly relevant websites:

1. [Crunchbang: [Solved] soundcard eclaro not working](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=20719)
2. [Ask Ubuntu: In need of driver for C-Media CMI8788](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165141/in-need-of-driver-for-c-media-cmi8788) - I really don't want to rip out alsa
3. [Ask Ubuntu: How can I enable my Asus Xonar DGX (CMI8788 chipset) sound card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192460/how-can-i-enable-my-asus-xonar-dgx-cmi8788-chipset-sound-card)

Comment: The eClaro model is not supported by the `snd-oxygen` driver. You have to wait until somebody finds the time to write the code to handle that particular combination of AK4396 and CS4362 DAC chips.